# Android BLE : UUID match [A-F0-9]{4} and [A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

[In the document](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery) ,the serivce's uuid is something like `[A-F0-9]{4}` while [Android BLE sevice's uuid](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattService.html#getUuid()) is something like '`[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}`'. And Schema docs say :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <xs:simpleType name="uuid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[A-F0-9]{4}" />
      <xs:pattern value="[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}" />
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

**Are they the same uuid OR just the same thing with different face?**
And Why there are two patterns?I think ONE is OK!
Any one can explain why are they not the same? OR can have some java code to convert one to the other ?

Comment: One of the pages you linked to explains this. Quote: _"[The SDP specification] defines a way to represent a range of UUIDs (which are nominally 128 bits) in a shorter form. A reserved range of 232 values can be represented using 32 bits (denoted uuid32). Of these, a sub-range of 216 values can be represented using only 16 bits (denoted uuid16)."_ The `[A-F0-9]{4}` pattern would match a `uuid16`, while the longer pattern would match a full 128-bit UUID.

Comment: @Michael In java how can I convert each other? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking someone on Hardware Work, I got a role mapping UUID32 to UUID128 example is:

```
FF12-->0000FF12-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

And via Google I got : [image]